# How to git add file each by each only show file name

Tags: git

Sometimes we edit several files at the same time, but maybe we only want to commit some of it, I used command mode for git, therefore there are only two ways I know to do `git add` files one by one.

First is just use `git status`, and copy file name which I want after `git add`, it was slow and tired, second is use `git commit -p`, it will show every detail you change and let you pick if it is the part you want to add, if you want to commit whole file, just input `a`.

It's quite convenient, but I use git in Windows 7, if git generated too much code, the screen will become a mess, so I am looking for the way to git add file one by one with only shows file name to check, hope there is a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `git add -i` for "interactive". It will open an interactive prompt, showing you all files which have changed. From there, you can select "update" and choose one or more files at a time to be staged. It works pretty much exactly as you've described.